# Anorm Mysql Stored Procedure calling

Tags: mysql, scala, stored-procedures, playframework, anorm

This is my simple stored procedure ,

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `TestDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test123`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test123`(id INT(11) , user_name VARCHAR(15), branch VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Testlog(id,user_name,branch)
VALUES(id,user_name,branch);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

i can run above stored procedure with below command in mysql

```
CALL `TestDB`.test123(3,"swap","desc")
```

but using anorm how to do that??

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
SQL("EXCE  test123 {id},{name},{branch}").
on('id -> 22,
'name -> "lcs",
'branch -> "desc").executeQuery()

}
```

How to run stored procedure in Anorm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this works for me

```
SQL("call  test123 ({id},{name},{branch})").
          on('id -> 21,
            'name -> "lcs",
            'branch -> "desc").executeUpdate()

}
```